# Why jumping into an instruction even if containing a JUMPDEST does not work?

Tags: assembly, ethereum, opcode, evm, stack-machine

Here’s my whole program. The reasoning behind it is the larger is the program on Ethereum, the more it costs money to load it (as the gas cost is per byte and quite high).

```
CALLER
CALLDATASIZE
ISZERO
PUSH1 0x07
JUMPI
PUSH3 0x5b6000
SSTORE
```

So I’m jumping into `PUSH3 0x5b6000` but if we disassemble `0x5b6000` then it means

```
JUMPDEST
PUSH1 0x00
```

So since the evm opcode encoding is [fully variable length](https://ethervm.io/) (and all instructions being one byte long beside PUSHxx) and I’m jumping into a `JUMPDEST`, why does [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcdb5bf0b4b51093e1c994f471921f88623c9d3e1b6aa2782049f53a0048f2b32) fails?

Where is it specified in the yellow paper that going to a `JUMPDEST` isn’t the only requirement for a valid jump destination?

Comment: **Please notice that there’s no program or tools for assembly a program completely written in Ethereum assembly.** It needs to be done completely by hand using an hex editor.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Note that this sort of jumping to the middle of instructions, while more common by the "masters" of the past, makes it incredibly hard for anyone to understand what's happening. However, the typical things to ask apply. Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: @ThomasJager then it behave as in the question’s transaction link described it which is `invalid jump destination` without telling why it’s invalid. Please note that on Ethereum fees are very high compared to traditional cloud computing which is the reasoning behind having programs as short as possible.

Comment: It might be worth it to migrate this question to the [Ethereum StackExchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about which version of the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) was available when this question was originally asked, but here is an excerpt from page 13 of the Istanbul version:

> 9.4.3. Jump Destination Validity. We previously used D as the function to determine the set of valid jump destinations given the code that is
> being run. We define this as any position in the code occupied by a
> JUMPDEST instruction.
>
> All such positions must be on valid instruction
> boundaries, rather than sitting in the data portion of PUSH operations
> and must appear within the explicitly defined portion of the code
> (rather than in the implicitly defined STOP operations that trail it).

And here is the geth [source location](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/401354976bb44f0ad4455ca1e0b5c0dc31d9a5f5/core/vm/analysis.go#L81) for the code that implements an anasysis for this.